# Search and count terms in a range of directories with multiple files

Tags: python

I'm trying to search a range of directories, for instance 20130901 to 20130919, each with multiple files in the directories, and search each file to count the number of times terms occur.

I can get it to work when I search only one directory, but I need to search several directories.  Here's what I have so far, but this doesn't work. It doesn't find any matches when there should be thousands for each term in all files in the directories

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import glob

vipmatches = "<vip>1</vip>"
nonvipmatches = "<vip>0</vip>"
vipwords = []
nonvipwords = []
numvip = 0
numnonvip = 0
paths ='20130919'

def scandirs(path):
        for currentFile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*') ):
                print currentFile
                with open(currentFile, 'r') as f:
                        for line in f:
                                for word in line.split():
                                        if word in vipmatches:
                                                vipwords.append(word)
                                        elif word in nonvipmatches:
                                                nonvipwords.append(word)
scandirs(paths)
numvips = len(vipwords)
numnonvips = len(nonvipwords)
print "%d vips, %d nonvips" % (numvips, numnonvips)
```

Can someone let me know if I'm going down the wrong path or what I'm doing wrong here?  Its much appreciated as always!

**Edit: I modified the code above with a working model, however this is only searching the one directory that I specify (20130919).  I've tried creating a list: `['20130919','20130918']` but the script errors out.  Any ideas on how to search a range of directories using scandirs?

Comment: Use `os.walk()` to walk directories in one loop.

Comment: You should switch to using four spaces to make all of that much more readable...

Comment: Did you call `scandirs`?

Comment: Should word be a substring of `vipmatches`? Because `'ip' in vipmatches` will be True as containment tests against strings work against substrings.

Comment: are these directories separate or inside eachother?

Comment: The files are in directories for each day, ex 20130919.  So for that directory, I need to search `./20130919/*`, `./20130918/*`, etc.